# отправить файл в ответ на post запрос

Tags: golang, golang-gin

У меня есть обработчик приходящего мне post запроса
По результатам обработки в качестве ответа мне нужно отправить обратно png картинку
Использую gin

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/generate", func(c *gin.Context) {
        f, err := os.Open("data.bin")
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        // вот прочитал я файл и хочу его отправить в ответ...
        c.???
        // вот если бы мне нужно было ответить в формате json, я бы написал c.JSON(...)
        // а как тут поступить
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.File?

Comment: Этот метод я видел, но он считывает файл с диска. Наверное я не очень правильно сформулировал вопрос...
Мне нужно уметь отправлять изображение QR которое я сгенерирую... файл был как пример

Answer (score 1):

Наверное мне удалось сделать

```
        f, err := os.Open("data.png")
        if err != nil {
            c.String(400, "reading file 'data.png' %v", err)
            return
        }
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
        c.Data(200, "png", b)
```

Что важно -- данные в буфере b могут быть соответственно произвольным набором байт и приёмник (если он ваш) вполне сможет сделать с ними то, что нужно.
На стороне приёмника:

```
    resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8080/generate", "application/json", bytes.NewReader([]byte(`{"wh":1,"num":2,"date":"2006-01-02"}`)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", err)
        return
    }
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    ioutil.WriteFile("data-resp.png", b, os.ModeExclusive)
```

уважаемый Ainar-G верно заметил, чтобы просто положить в body ответа именно файл (путь к которому вам известен) лучше воспользоваться
[Context.File](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.File)

Answer (score 1):

не важно в ответ на какой запрос вы вызовете это, он отправил пользователю файл на скачивание:

```
func downloadFile(c *gin.Context) {

    c.FileAttachment("./userFiles/usrFile1.txt", "test.txt")

}
```

1 аргумент это адрес, второй это имя, которое установится файлу при скачке пользователем